# Joining two dataframes on unique ID, but using another value if id doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as such:

```
UID    mainColumn .... (other columns of data)
1      apple
2      orange
3      apple
4      orange
5      berry
....

UID2   mainColumn2
1      truck
3      car
4      boat
5      plane
...
```

I need to join the second dataframe onto dataframe based on UID, however if df2 does not contain a uid, then the maincolumn value is the one I'd to use. In the above example, UID2 does not contain the value 2, so the final table would look something like

```
UID    mainColumn ....
1      truck
2      orange
3      car
4      boat
5      plane
...
```

Now I'm aware we can do something in the form of

```
df1=df1.merge(df2,left_on='UID', right_on='UID2')
```

But the issue I have is not replacing the missing values, and making sure they are still included. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldnt `UID 3` in your final table be `car`?

Comment: @Erfan yes it should! Fixed thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) after renaming the columns of `df2` as `df1` (eg UID2 to UID..) :

```
df2.columns=df1.columns#be careful, rename only matching columns
final_df=df2.set_index('UID').combine_first(df1.set_index('UID')).reset_index()
```

---

```
  UID mainColumn
0    1      truck
1    2     orange
2    3        car
3    4       boat
4    5      plane
```

Answer (score 0):

We can first use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) the missing values and finally [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the extra column:

```
final = df1.merge(df2, left_on='UID', right_on='UID2', how='left').drop('UID2', axis=1)

final['mainColumn'] = final['mainColumn2'].fillna(final['mainColumn'])

final.drop('mainColumn2', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

```
   UID mainColumn
0    1      truck
1    2     orange
2    3        car
3    4       boat
4    5      plane
```